# PHP: json_decode returns NULL (Paytm checksum generation)

Tags: php, json, paytm

I am trying to generate checksum for Paytm payment gateway using php.

```
<?php

// following files need to be included
require_once("./lib/config_paytm.php");
require_once("./lib/encdec_paytm.php");

if (strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') != 0) {
    throw new Exception('Request method must be POST');
}

$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));


$decodeData = json_decode($content, true);
// var_dump($decodeData); // this return null

if (!empty($decodeData)) {
    $paramList = array();

    $paramList["MID"] = $decodeData["MID"]; //Provided by Paytm
    $paramList["ORDER_ID"] = $decodeData["ORDER_ID"]; //unique OrderId for every request
    $paramList["CUST_ID"] = $decodeData["CUST_ID"]; // unique customer identifier 
    $paramList["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = $decodeData["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"]; //Provided by Paytm
    $paramList["CHANNEL_ID"] = $decodeData["CHANNEL_ID"]; //Provided by Paytm
    $paramList["TXN_AMOUNT"] = $decodeData["TXN_AMOUNT"]; // transaction amount
    $paramList["WEBSITE"] = $decodeData["WEBSITE"]; //Provided by Paytm
    $paramList["CALLBACK_URL"] = $decodeData["CALLBACK_URL"]; //Provided by Paytm
    // $paramList["EMAIL"] = $decodeData["MID"]; // customer email id
    $paramList["MOBILE_NO"] = $decodeData["MOBILE_NO"]; // customer 10 digit mobile no.


    $checkSum = getChecksumFromArray($paramList, PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY);

    if (!empty($checkSum)) {
        echo json_encode(array("CHECKSUMHASH" => $checkSum));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("ORDER_ID" => $decodeData["ORDER_ID"]));
    }
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong";
}

if (!is_array($decodeData)) {
    throw new Exception(('Recieved content containes invalid JSON'));
}
```

Turns out `json_decode` returns `NULL`. i.e. `$decodeData` is `NULL`. 
Tho `$content` returns right details.

> One thing to point out is `$content` contains `PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY`
>   which have special characters like @ and %. Is that's the reason
>   `json_decode` is unable to decode the data?

Or there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Maybe the data you get from `$content` is not json? and when you try to decode it, you get the `NULL` value.

Comment: Could you show what `$content` contains.

Comment: [`json_last_error_msg()`](https://www.php.net/json_last_error_msg)

Comment: turns out $content is not in JSON. Silly me .